# Append line only when 2 search criteria are met

Tags: bash, sed

I want to accomplish the following with sed
1.Find first occurrence of [sometext] **Exact match**

2.Then start search from there for stuID = 10  **Exact match**

3.Then append line checkID = 4 for the first occurance of stuID under [sometext]

Note : the value of checkID will change according to [sometext] that's why i need to append line for first occurance only

My attempts

> sed '/[sometext]/{ s/stuID = 10/a\checkID = 4/1 }' file.txt
>
> sed 's/[sometext]/{ s/stuID = 10/a\checkID = 4/1 }' file.txt
>
> sed '/[sometext]/{ s/stuID = 10/a\checkID = 4/g }' file.txt

{just to see if command works if i don't specify the number of times to add new line.

> I added \ ] to escape []

Results

1.Command get executed but checkID=4 is not added anywhere in file.txt

2.Error : sed: -e expression #1, char 18: multiple `g' options to` s' command
Implying that syntax itself is wrong

3.Command get executed but checkID=4 is not added anywhere in file.txt

When i say executed i mean there is no error message

File.txt

```
[sometext]
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
stuID = 10 
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
[Anothertext]
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
stuID = 5
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
```

I want it to be
File.txt

```
[sometext]
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
stuID = 10 
checkID=4 
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
[Anothertext]
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
stuID = 5
checkID=6
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
```

I am completely tired and clueless at this point .Hope someone can help me out

Regards

Comment: Hint: awk is much better tool to handle this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/\[sometext\]/,/stuID = 10/{/stuID = 10/{a\checkID = 4' -e ':a;n;ba}}' file
```

This finds the range between the 2 search strings and appends the desired text. Finally the rest of the file is passed over.

Comment: Thanks for the response mate but can u please explain this part `:a;n;ba`

Comment: Dude when i run the script , it show newline as expected , but when i open the file after the bash has run the new line don't appear

Comment: By newline i mean checkID=4

Comment: Ignore my comments above , just a stupid error in location for file